# Setting redis configuration with docker in windows

Tags: maven, docker, redis

I want to set up redis configuration in docker.

I have my own redis.conf under `D:/redis/redis.conf` and have configured it to have bind `127.0.0.1` and have uncommented requirepass foobared

Then used this command to load this configuration in docker:

```
docker run --volume D:/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --name myredis redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Next,
I have docker-compose.yml in my application in maven Project under `src/resources`.

I have the following in my docker-compase.yml

```
redis:
 image: redis
 ports:
   - "6379:6379"
```

And i execute the command :

```
docker-compose up
```

The Server runs, but when i check with the command:

```
docker ps -a
```

it Shows that redis Image runs at 0.0.0.0:6379.

I want it to run at 127.0.0.1.

How do i get that?
isn't my configuration file loading or is it wrong? or my commands are wrong?

Any suggestions are of great help.

PS: I am using Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute:

```
docker inspect <container_id>
```

And use "NetworkSettings"->"Gateway" (it must be 172.17.0.1) value instead of 127.0.0.1.

You can't use 127.0.0.1 as your Redis was run in the isolated environment.

Or you can link your containers.

Comment: Thanks for ur Reply @Aleksandr Yes it Shows 172.17.0.1. And i changed the bind at redis.conf to bind 172.17.0.1. But again when i do execute the command docker run --volume D:/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --name myredis redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf and execute the command docker-compose up it Shows the same

Answer (score 1):

So first of all you should not be worried about redis saying listening on `0.0.0.0:6379`. Because redis is running inside the container. And if it doesn't listen on `0.0.0.0` then you won't be able to make any connections.

Next if you want redis to only listen on localhost on localhost then you need to use below

```
redis:
 image: redis
 ports:
   - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"
```

PS: I have not run container or docker for windows with `127.0.0.1` port mapping, so you will have to see if it works. Because host networking in Windows, Mac and Linux are different and may not work this way

Comment: thanks for ur Reply. I tried what u said, but surprisingly it says Bind for 127.0.0.1:6379 failed:port is alread allocated. Have no idea what is happening

Comment: i just noticed that whenever i Change the bind or uncomment the requirepass, then i get that Connection refused, incase i Keep the ip to 127.0.0.1 or the Gateway and give Password as null in my redis.yml then it works. SO i think my redis.conf isnt loading properly though it Shows configuration loaded

Comment: Assuming you are using Docker for Windows, is your `D:` shared in Docker settings with the Docker VM?

Comment: yes i can see my drive being shared in docker settings

Comment: The redis bind should always be `0.0.0.0` in config. Also run `docker-compose exec redis cat /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf` to make sure the config you passed is inside the container

Comment: i tried this command but it Shows No conatiner found for redis_1

Comment: You need to run it after `docker-compose up -d` and also the name redis has to be same as the one your used for service

Comment: yes i did the same. but it Shows No such service: resources_redis_1 although docker compse is running and Shows ready to accept connections

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156254/discussion-between-pgman-and-tarun-lalwani).